# Omitted Variables in Partial Least Squares

Tags: regression, partial-least-squares

Suppose I run PLS of $y$ on $X$, where $y$ is a 1-dimensional and $X$ is n-dimensional. If I deleted some variables (columns) in the matrix $X$, how would the loadings and the factors behave? Will it suffer from something like omitted variables bias in multiple linear regression?

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit? Omitted variable bias would appear as soon as you leave out one or more __relevant variables__, so I would say everything depends on what columns you remove...

Comment: Maybe the term 'omitted variable bias' is a bit confusing in the context. My problem is actually the first one: say if one variable $X_k$ is deleted from $X$, can we have some relationship with the results with all $X$ variables?

Comment: Theoretically, as soon as there is some correlation between the $X_i$ then the results will change if you remove some of the $X_i$.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that. I am looking for any particular structure, especially in terms of covariance of $X_i$ and $X$.